# Execute a function after for loop is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked at several examples of callback functions but they don't seem to answer my question.
I would like `myFunction2()` (see below code) to be executed after the `for loop` is completed, unfortunately this is being called before `for loop` is completed (possibly due to API calls in for loop).

Can someone please advise how I can ensure that `myFunction2()` is called only after the completion of `for loop`.

```
function myFunction(){
 for(var i =0; i<array1.length; i++){
    // contains code with API calls
 }
 myFunction2();
}
```

Comment: Simple idea: Keep a counter of how many API calls are finished. After the count becomes as the no. of calls, call the function.

Comment: Check out [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [JavaScript Promises: There and back again](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), [JavaScript Promises](https://davidwalsh.name/promises)

Answer (score 0):

function two called after loop finish it's process. or you can use count to ensure length and count of loop traverse are equal. then and then only call function 2

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>win_load_vs_doc_load</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $arr=["a","a1","a2","a3"];
        myFunction();
        function myFunction()
        {
            for(var i =0; i<=$arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(i==$arr.length)
                    {
                        myFunction2();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        alert(i);
                    }
            }
        }

        function myFunction2()
        {
            alert("myFunction2 called");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This will only work because `alert()` stops the execution. But the API calls in the question are asynchronous.

Comment: try to comment that alert, and set $count to 1.

Comment: Replace the first alert with an asynchronous function (`XMLHttpRequest`, `window.fetch`,...) and the second with `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the API is called asynchronously and the JavaScript function is finished till the result from API call gets back,

The simplest solution is by **callback**. Just give that API call a callback function to execute when it returns, but since you didn't give the API call code, there is one more method to do it.

Make the API code **synchronous**. It's not recommended to make API calls synchronous because it'll block the rest of the code from working if API call takes a lot of time, but it's possible.

For example: `jQuery.ajax()` has `async (default: true)` property which if set to false makes ajax request synchronous.

NOTE: **async is deprecated** so don't use it, I just told you because it's a way to do it. Use the callback functions like success or fail!
 like this (assuming API call is ajax):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },

  success: function2;

})
```

Hope this answers your question, if not then paste your API call code here.

Comment: **Never** ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice, should never be used and is deprecated. Will see warnings in console about this deprecation. There is no need to ever use it either

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `$.ajax` you can use array of promises for each call and use `$.when()` to execute when all those promises are resolved.

```
function myFunction(){
 var promises = array1.map(function(arrayElement){
      // arrayElement is same as array1[i] in your loop    
      var data = // get what you need from arrayElement
      // return the promise that is returned from $.ajax`
      return $.get(url, data).done(function(resp){
          // do whatever you do with the response
      });    
 });

 $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
    // code here gets called whan all api requests have successfully completed
    myFunction2();

 }).fail(function(err){
     // not all requests succeeded
 })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute `$.when()` using `.apply()`, `$.map()` for `for` loop

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(array1, function(request) {
  // do api stuff
  return $.ajax(request)
}))
// call `myFunction2` when all api stuff completed
.then(myFunction2
// handle error of api call
, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
})
```